# Retrieving KeySet from LinkedHashMap in specified order

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, treeset

I am writing a program which extracts keys from a `List of LinkedHashMap`. Extracted keys will then be concatenated with commas and printed as column headers in a CSV file.

Sample content of the `flatJson` looks like this:

```
{
  Submitted_Date=03-11-2016 01:19:41, 
  Comments=, 
  Rating=3,
  details.name=Willy,  
  details.personalId=S123456A,
  details.mobileNo=11111111, 
  details.email=willy@email.com,
  Channel=desktop, 
  Referral_Code=, 
  discount.promoCode=,
  discount.referral=, 
  policyPlan.grossPremium=788.64,
  policyPlan.name=Standard, 
  policyPlan.netPremium=788.64
}
```

Code:

```
private TreeSet<String> collectHeaders(List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> flatJson) {
    TreeSet<String> headers = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedMap : flatJson) {
        headers.addAll(linkedMap.keySet());
    }
    return headers;
}
```

The order of headers I am getting from this program is:

```
Channel
Comments
Rating
Referral_Code
Submitted_Date
details.email
details.personalId
details.mobileNo
details.name
discount.promoCode
discount.referral
policyPlan.grossPremium
policyPlan.name
policyPlan.netPremium
```

While the expected output is the same as the `flatJson`:

```
Submitted_Date
Comments
Rating
details.name
details.personalId
details.mobileNo
details.email
Channel
Referral_code
discount.promoCode
discount.referral
policyPlan.grossPremium
policyPlan.name
policyPlan.netPremium
```

Previously, I were using `HashMap` and `Set` which don't support ordering. I have since changed them to `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeSet` but still can't get the right order.

Comment: Use LinkedHashSet instead of TreeSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TreeSet is not about preserving **insertion** order. It is about **sorting** its elements.

In other words: if you add **String** objects to a TreeSet, they get *ordered* as if you would be *sorting* that list!

So, if *order* is your primary concern, you should use the [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead of TreeSet! Alternatively, you could provide a custom [Comparator](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/implement-comparable-for-a-treeset/) upon creating your TreeSet ... that somehow gives you that order you are looking for - that might work, but smells like hackish workaround to me.

Comment: Changing it to LinkedHasSet immediately solved the issue. Thank you very much!